# How do I solve colcon build on Ubuntu?

Tags: cmake, ros

The error reads as follows:

```
By not providing "Findrosidl_default_generators.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided
  by "rosidl_default_generators", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "rosidl_default_generators" with any of the following names:

    rosidl_default_generatorsConfig.cmake
    rosidl_default_generators-config.cmake
```

Comment: Please, describe (list them in the question post) your steps for building the package.

Comment: Check where the cmake config script mentioned in the console output recides and specify the correct path in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Pretty much what the cmake output instructs you to do...

Comment: source /opt/ros/crystal/setup.bash and colcon build --merge-install --packages-skip individual_trajectories_bridge

Comment: For me I just forgot to source ROS. Try source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash and then build.